# Space between checkbox options in column

Tags: sharepoint-online

I have a column in a library which allows the user to select from various options to tag the library item.

The issue is that when displayed in the view all the options that have been chosen are grouped together without any spaces and separated with a comma. This then makes the column very wide.

Is there a way to ensure a space is included so that the text wraps in the column space available?

Thanks

**Picture 1: As displayed in the list view, makes column very wide**

[image: As displayed in the list view, makes column very wide]

**Picture 2: settings for column**

[image: settings for column]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could edit the view webpart to add in a JSLink piece of code that replaces the commas with comma,spaces - that would probably allow the field to wrap. I used split/join, you could do a regex replace or whatever you need.

```
var jsl = jsl || {};
 jsl.AddSpaces = function() { 
     var ctx = {};
     ctx.Templates = {};
     ctx.Templates.Fields = {
      "Structural_x0020_Element": {"View": jsl.AddSpaceOverride}
     };
     SPClientTemplates.TemplateManager.RegisterTemplateOverrides(ctx);
};

 jsl.AddSpaceOverride = function(ctx) {

  if(ctx.CurrentItem.Structural_x0020_Element) {
      var newVal = ctx.CurrentItem.Structural_x0020_Element.toString();
      return newVal.split(',').join(', ');
   } else {
      return "";
   } 
}

 jsl.AddSpaces();
```

Comment: I added your code to a file and linked it to the JSLink fields in the edit webpart box but nothing happens. Any ideas?

Comment: I've also tried a variation of your code using the cisar browser extension but again, nothing happens to the view.

Comment: Are you sure it's actually running? In the webpart section, the link to the file needs to be ~site/YOURDOCLIBR/filename.fileext - make sure you've got the ~site not an absolute. You can test if it's running by adding alert('hi'); as the first line of AddSpaces function. I'm hoping it's not an SPO problem - I'm on premise not online...

Comment: using `alert('hi');` as you mentioned works so the script is running, just not altering the values in the column...

Comment: That's good news at least. The next thing that could be wrong is your internal name for your field is incorrect, or maybe you're getting an error somewhere, like at the split. It took me awhile to get it to work - F12 debugger was always showing me I was splitting on a null - maybe F12 will show you something?
When I was debugging I had an alert in the AddSpaceOverride function (making sure I only had a few items in the view) so I could verify it was running and what value I was getting - alert(ctx.CurrentItem.Structural_x0020_Element.toString());

Comment: The field name had been changed, the first thing I should have checked! One more... Probably changes the code a lot but I need to do this for multiple columns. I can just copy the code for each column that is fine but is there an easier way in your opinion? Like to loop through an array of column names?

Comment: :)
You can add your other column names in ctx.Templates.Fields section of AddSpaces , just add a comma and add in your other column names. ctx.Templates.Fields = {
      "Structural_x0020_Element": {"View": jsl.AddSpaceOverride}, "Column2": {"View":jsl.AddSpceOverride}    };  Then, in AddSpaceOverride, you'd have to remove the actual field name and grab the 'current' value - not sure if ctx has a 'this' type of structure. I'll go google and see what I can find

Comment: It looks like you can generalize the value in AddSpaceOverride  - you can clean it up, I was trying to be careful to get around nulls
  var newVal = ctx.CurrentItem[ctx.CurrentFieldSchema.Name];

if(newVal) {
      var newVal = newVal.toString();
      return newVal.split(',').join(', ');
   }